# Le groupe du nom peut-il être un complément indirect d'un verbe?

Tags: grammaire, compléments, groupe-nominal

Dans la phrase « Je vais à l'école », est-ce que le complément indirect « à l'école » est un groupe du nom? Ou bien il faut le considérer comme un groupe prépositionnel?

Je suis surpris que dans les questions simples comme ça, il n'y pas une seule opinion dans différents manuels de grammaire.

Est-ce qu'un groupe de nom peut être un complément indirect?

Answer (score 4):

Les grammaires n'utilisent pas toutes les mêmes termes, mais ce qui compte, c'est de comprendre les concepts. Et encore: les locuteurs natifs appliquent les concepts intuitivement, sans forcément les comprendre.

Wikipédia résume ce cas dans l'article [syntagme](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupe_nominal#Syntagme_nominal) — un syntagme est un fragment de phrase qui forme une unité grammaticale cohérente. Un *syntagme nominal*, ou *groupe nominal*, est un syntagme dont le mot principal (le *noyau*) est un nom. Si le mot principal est un verbe, on parle de *groupe verbal* (ou *syntagme verbal*) ; un adjectif, de *groupe adjectivial* ; un adverbe, de *groupe adverbial*, etc.

Suivant cette logique, un *groupe prépositionnel* ou *syntagme prépositionnel* devrait être un syntagme dont le mot principal est une préposition. Toutefois cette notion est contestée en français ; si l'on considère qu'il n'y a pas de syntagme dont le mot principal est une préposition, cela libère l'expression pour autre chose. Des constructions comme « longtemps avant » (« il s'est levé longtemps avant l'aube ») sont analysées tantôt comme des syntagmes dont le noyau est la préposition (l'adverbe *longtemps* étant alors un complément de la préposition *avant*), tantôt comme des [locutions](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locution_(linguistique)) dont la structure est figée. (Je ne comprends pas pourquoi des cas comme « longtemps avant » ne devraient pas être considérés comme des syntagmes.)

Lorsque le groupe nominal est introduit par une préposition, il y a deux syntagmes : « l'école » est un groupe nominal, et « à l'école » est aussi un syntagme. Certains grammairiens parlent de *groupe prépositionnel* pour « à l'école » ; ce syntagme est quand même un groupe nominal : c'est un **groupe nominal prépositionnel**, c'est-à-dire un syntagme dont le noyau est un nom et qui est de plus introduit par une préposition. On peut aussi avoir des groupes verbaux prépositionnels, par exemple « à lire » dans « il apprend à lire ».

Comment: Il semble que le terme "groupe nominal prépositionnel" est répandu en Europe, mais n'est pas rencontré au Québec. Dans le dernier cas on parle seulement de GN ou de GPrep. Ceci engender des confusions dans les cas comme "Je vais aux écoles". "Aux écoles", est un groupe prépositionnel ou nominal?

Answer (score 2):

Si je ne m'abuse, « l'école » est un groupe nominal et « à l'école » est un groupe prépositionnel, « vais à l'école » un groupe verbal et « Je vais à l'école » une phrase.

C'est un arbre, voir [Phrase structure (grammar)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase-structure_grammar) sur Wikipedia.

Comment: Je ne vois pas le rapport entre le lien vers Wikipedia (qui concerne un type de grammaire formelle, j'ai jamais vu une grammaire de ce type donnée pour le français) et la question.

Comment: Ça s'imbrique ? Quand on rajoute des mots autour d'un noyau on change sa fonction grammaticale (la position dans la phrase étant l'autre variable).

Comment: Pour le français, http://alpage.inria.fr/statgram/frdep/fr_stat_dep_parsing.html , qui rejoint FFF et Wordnet français comme projets de base de linguistique automatique du français.

Comment: C'est logique mais qu'est qu'on dirait pour "Je vais aux écoles"? Est-ce que "aux écoles" est un groupe nominal ou prépositionnel?

Comment: Pour moi, "les écoles" est un groupe nominal et "aux écoles" un groupe prépositionnel, car on peut mettre ce dernier dans un phrase à un endroit qui appelle un groupe prépositionnel en "à".