# Le groupe prépositionnel ne peut être complément direct ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, infinitif

La [*préposition*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4327) dispose des rapports logiques entre les éléments qu'elle lie. On lit qu'un *groupe prépositionnel*, formé d'une préposition étendue par un groupe quelconque, dont l'infinitif, peut avoir n'importe quelle fonction sauf celle de sujet et de *complément direct*. Par exemple, en complément indirect : *J’ai songé à démissionner*. [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique*, « La préposition et le groupe prépositionnel » ]

---

Je suis peu familier avec l'[analyse](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11739/3177) de la fonction d'un tel groupe. Dans « [je veux *à boire*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z4EqAAAAYAAJ&jtp=231) », le *[à](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) [boire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/boire)* est-il un groupe prépositionnel infinitif complément direct ? Sinon quelle est sa nature et sa fonction ici ? Et généralement pourquoi un groupe prépositionnel, formé par exemple d'un noyau avec « à », ne pourrait-il pas être un complément direct d'un verbe transitif direct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*À boire* (ainsi que *à manger*) est un groupe prépositionnel qui a la particularité d'agir syntaxiquement comme un groupe nominal.

Je ne sais pas s'il s'agit d'une élision de *quelque chose* ou si l'étymologie est différente, mais si on le présume, justement, comme un variante de *quelque chose à boire*, la construction est assez limpide, d'autant plus que *boire* et *manger* font déjà partie les rares infinitifs qui se nominalisent directement.

---

Pour (tenter de) répondre aux questions supplémentaire, *à boire/manger* **est une exception à la règle**. Normalement un groupe prépositionnel **ne peux jamais** être un complément direct, point final (à cause de la définition même de complément direct). Ce n'est pas la présence ou non d'un groupe nominal qui fait la différence en dehors du *cas spécifique* qui nous intéresse.

La seule situation que je connaisse en français où un élément du groupe nominal autre que le nom vient affecter le verbe, c'est le cas des possesseurs de parties du corps, dans des constructions comme *je me cogne la tête* ou *je lui rase la barbe*. Je parle un peu plus de ce cas particulier avec liens à l'appui [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14727/926).

Un verbe peut **requérir** la présence d'un groupe prépositionnel, mais il ne s'agit pas alors d'un complément direct. Les anglais parlent d'*oblique complements*, mais je ne suis pas parvenu à trouver le terme équivalent en français. Un exemple est verbe *aller*, d'où le fait qu'on disent *j'y vais* ou *je m'en vais* (les pronoms remplaçant ici des groupes prépositionnels obligatoires).

Quand je parle d'infinitif qui se nominalisent, je parlent en effet des quelques cas qui s'emploient comme nom défini. *Boire* et *manger* sont les seuls que je connaissent, mais il y est possible qu'il y en ait d'autres. Ils ne s'emploient jamais qu'au singulier. Quelques exemples tirés du *[Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/)*:

- *Il mettait toute son âme à bien soigner **ce manger**, dont les copains regardaient avidement la vapeur*
- À toute heure du jour, des équipes d'ouvriers vont et viennent le long des cafés au front bas où l'on peut «apporter **son manger**»
- Je sens [...] que je vais en perdre **le boire et le manger**.

De manière générale, c'est toutefois là un tour très recherché.

Comment: Je pense que l'on peut trouver d'autres exemples qui utilisent des ellipses pour donner des COD introduits par une préposition. Peut-être un peu artificiel, mais que j'ai déjà entendu et utilisé : « J'ai (matière) à penser. » Cela demeure certes une exception. Je ne peux pas mettre un second +1 pour la mise à jour de la réponse.

Comment: @chop Un exemple intéressant parce qu'il a la même origine, mais je crois qu'il a donné quelque chose de différent. À mon avis, dans ce cas, le résultat n'est pas la formation d'un groupe prépositionnel anormal mais plutôt d'une nouvelle construction syntaxique de *avoir*.

Comment: @Circeus Cela signifierait que « J'ai à manger » est différent de « Je donne à manger » ? « Tu m'as donné à penser » me semble tout aussi valable. Je pense que ces cas sont tous liés par leur nature.

Comment: @Circeus Quelques exemples de verbes qui se nominalisent très bien : le savoir faire, le parler, le souper, &hellip;

Comment: Merci, ça répond en partie à ma question http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14723/quel-est-le-cod-dans-il-se-rase-la-barbe

Answer (score 1):

Intéressant. On m'a toujours enseigné qu'une préposition signifie que l'on est en présence d'un complément d'objet indirect (COI) et non direct (COD).

### Direct ou indirect ?

Je me permets de modifier un peu l'exemple de la question originale.

> Je donne à boire à mon ami.

Je donne *quoi* ? « À boire » → COD
Je le donne ***à** qui* ? « À mon ami » → COI

Ainsi que [le dit Circeus](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14756/7224), « à boire » se comporte ici syntaxiquement comme un COD en dépit de sa préposition.

### L'explication

Mon premier réflexe a été comme lui de penser à une ellipse :

> Je donne (quelque chose) à boire à mon ami.

Le COD est ici le groupe nominal « quelque chose à boire », avec « à boire » étant un groupe prépositionnel attribut du complément.<sup>1</sup>

[Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_(grammaire)#Compl.C3.A9ment_d.27objet_direct) semble confirmer ceci :

> Une préposition peut cependant apparaître par ellipse, sans avoir cependant de rôle introductif : dans *je fais **à manger***, *à manger* est un COD - par ellipse de « *quelque chose* à manger ». La question portant sur l'objet du verbe n'est pas introduite par une préposition (« Que fais-je ? » et non « À quoi fais-je ? »).

### Questions annexes

#### Nominalisation/substantif

> … *boire* et *manger* font déjà partie les rares infinitifs qui se nominalisent directement. (Circeus)
>   Quand on dit des infinitifs qui se nominalisent, on veut dire qu'on peut les employer comme substantif, un peu comme *je veux du manger* ... ? (Riguefort Ultraquaillette)

[D'après le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/manger#Nom_commun), il ne s'agit pas là d'un substantif, mais bien d'un nom commun selon la définition courante.

À savoir que l'exemple *je veux du manger* est intéressant puisqu'ici, le groupe qui doit jouer le rôle de COD est introduit par « du ». Il ne s'agit pas ici de la préposition « de » mais de [l'article partitif « du »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_partitif) (*je bois de l'eau*, *je mange du chocolat*).

#### Deuxième commentaire

> Est-ce que je dois comprendre de la réponse que dans ce type de construction, la présence d'un GN complément quelconque va toujours empêcher qu'un GPrep le suivant (expansion) d'être complément direct. La fonction ne déborde pas du GN ? Je ne connais que le complément d'objet direct; dois-je faire une nuance avec le complément direct en contexte. (Riguefort Ultraquaillette)

Si le GPrép est un complément du nom, il n'est pas complément d'objet en lui-même. Le complément direct sera GN + GPrép CdN, les deux ne seront pas dissociables (ou plus exactement, le GPrép se rapportera au GN et n'aura donc aucun rôle vis-à-vis du verbe ou du sujet).

Je pense que le plus simple pour savoir si on a un CO et s'il est direct ou non est d'utiliser les deux questions : **Quoi ? (COD) *À* qui ? (COI)**

Attention cependant à garder en tête que celles-ci ne s'appliquent que pour des verbes transitifs : dans « Elle est à tomber », elle est quoi ? « À tomber ». Mais le verbe est intransitif : ce n'est pas un CO mais un attribut du sujet.

Il existe également d'autres formes de compléments. Pour ne reprendre qu'un exemple de [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d%27objet_direct) :

> Je marcherai les yeux fixés sur mes pensées (Victor Hugo)

« Les yeux fixés » est un complément circonstanciel et « sur mes pensées » un GPrép se rattachant à ce complément.

Je ne suis pas certain d'avoir répondu à toutes les questions mais j'espère avoir aidé.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Manque d'aisance de ma part ici : le [GPrép expansion du GN](http://bv.alloprof.qc.ca/francais/la-grammaire-de-la-phrase/les-groupes-de-mots/le-groupe-nominal.aspx#a3) fait-il partie du GN (comme un épithète) ou est-il un groupe complètement distinct ?</sub>

<sub>Cette réponse se base sur [celle de Circeus](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14756/7224) et tente d'intégrer des réponses aux questions de [Riguefort Ultraquaillette](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/3177/riguefort-ultraquaillette) en commentaire.</sub>

Comment: @RiguefortUltraquaillette Attribut du complément, c'est juste. Merci, je vais corriger. Substantif désigne pour moi un mot qui n'est pas forcément un nom mais est utilisé comme tel (_le_ + <verbe>, _la_ + <adjectif>). Je peine à trouver de bons exemples car tous ceux proposés par [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantif) ont une définition en tant que nom dans le Wiktionnaire.

Comment: @RiguefortUltraquaillette Concernant la phrase _je vais aux fraises_, je ne vois pas de partitif. Je ne sais pas ce qu'est un partitif de lieu. L'article partitif est un déterminant au même titre que _le_, _la_, &hellip; Il sert à marquer le fait que l'on ne considère qu'une **partie** d'un ensemble pas forcément comptable : je ne bois pas l'eau, parce que je ne peux pas la mesurer ; je bois _de l'_ eau. À ne pas confondre donc avec préposition _de_ + article défini : je parle de _l'_eau.